# Is there a best name for the "spinner" user input?

Tags: forms, input-fields, spinner, preloader

I like to go look at other peoples examples of interface layouts and design patterns. The other day I went to go look at design patterns for the standard "spinner" user input...

[image]

...but found that a lot of my search variations pulled up another design component. This "loading" spinner image is used as a placeholder to communicate to users that a page or section is loading...

[image]

The problem with this is that now there is a potential confusion. I guess what is driving my question is that I also want to practice good usability in my communications with business stakeholders and team members. I don't want there to be a miscommunication due to the way I refer to this widget.

Is there a best name for the "spinner" user input that does not result in potential misinterpretation?

Comment: I typically refer to it as: Loading Gif

Comment: Thanks for your input Xtian. Yah, I too usually call those round ones "loading gifs". I'm mainly concerned with the input image above the round ones that has the "57" in it. What would you call that?

Comment: In MFC they are called Spin buttons.

Answer (score 3):

iOS calls this a "stepper" (usually associated with some feedback of the value)

[image]

A "spinner" on Android is similar to what you are referring to, though there are no increment buttons

[image]

And what I would call a "loading animation" is called an "Activity Circle" or "Activity Indicator" on Android & iOS respectively.

[image]

[iOS Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH15-SW1)

[Android Guidelines (Progress & Activity)](https://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html)

Answer (score 1):

I never like calling that input a "spinner" unless it looped back around through the input values.

On iOS it is called a "Stepper" since you incrementally step between values. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

I did some research while I was waiting for answers...

http://uxfindings.blogspot.com/2014/06/is-numeric-spinner-best-name-for-this.html

Answer (score 0):

If you feel there might be confusion and need to be specific, call it a [*number input spinner*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=range%20slider&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=x7ehU5BfkPegBOfUgNgD&ved=0CCIQsAQ&biw=1125&bih=941#q=number%20input%20spinner&tbm=isch). The other type of spinner that reassures the user that there is still content to come is called a [*loading spinner.*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=range%20slider&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=x7ehU5BfkPegBOfUgNgD&ved=0CCIQsAQ&biw=1125&bih=941#q=loading%20spinner&tbm=isch)

There is a similar name conflict between the [*range slider*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=range%20slider&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=x7ehU5BfkPegBOfUgNgD&ved=0CCIQsAQ&biw=1125&bih=941) and [*image slider*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=range%20slider&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=x7ehU5BfkPegBOfUgNgD&ved=0CCIQsAQ&biw=1125&bih=941#q=image%20slider&tbm=isch).